# Problem with CSS layout with wrapping text

Tags: css, layout, grid

I'm trying to replace some layouts table layouts with css layouts and have this code:

```
<html>
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
  #grid{
   border:solid;
   border-width:1px;
   border-color:#000000;
   width:300px;
   max-width:300px;
   min-width:300px;
   overflow:hidden;
   font-size:14px;
  }

  #grid .item{
   text-align:center;
   width:33%;
   margin-top:2px;
   margin-bottom:2px;
   float:left;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="wagerStream">
  <div id="grid">
   <div class="item">item1</div>
   <div class="item">item2</div>
   <div class="item">item3</div>
   <div class="item">item4</div>
   <div class="item">item5</div>
   <div class="item">item6</div>
   <div class="item">item7</div>
   <div class="item">item8</div>
   <div class="item">item9</div>
  </div>
  <div id="grid">
   <div class="item">item1</div>
   <div class="item">item2</div>
   <div class="item">item3</div>
   <div class="item">item4 with wrapping text</div>
   <div class="item">item5</div>
   <div class="item">item6</div>
   <div class="item">item7</div>
   <div class="item">item8</div>
   <div class="item">item9</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see I have a problem with the way the last three items display when wrapping text occurs and would to know what would be a good css solution.

Comment: You can't have two elements with id="grid". Also, depending on what you're trying to represent, it looks like you have a serious case of Divitus.

Answer (score 0):

set additional two styles on `item` class:

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: thanks, that works but is there a way to keep the text and make item5 and item6 increase their height to match item4's instead?

Comment: Unfortunately not without javascript or wrapping rows together.

Comment: Ok,I guess I'll use javascript to set the others elements height equal to the biggest one.

Comment: You can find scripts for that on the net http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+equal+height+columns

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify a height to the `.item`. Because floating elements always set their height to the minimum they need.
So, add the following line to your `.item`

```
height:<amount>px;
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I could think of without using JavaScript and without specifying a set height to your items, is to wrap every 3 items in a row.

```
<div id="grid">
   <div class="item-row">
      <div class="item">item1</div>
      <div class="item">item2</div>
      <div class="item">item3</div>
   </div>
   <div class="item-row">
      <div class="item">item4 with wrapping text</div>
      <div class="item">item5</div>
      <div class="item">item6</div>
   </div>
   <div class="item-row">
      <div class="item">item7</div>
      <div class="item">item8</div>
      <div class="item">item9</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

You'd want to have `overflow:hidden` applied to `item-row` to contain the floated items.